# Trigger touchmove event drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, drag-and-drop, touchmove

Hi I need to trigger a touchmove event manually and pull an element out of the countainer on a mobile device (phonegap, jquery-mobile)

```
$(elem).bind('touchstart', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();                  
        var target = event.target;
        target = $(this);

        //this for example just changes the css position obviously
        target.css("margin-top", "50px"); 
});


elem.trigger('touchstart');
```

Is there a way to setup a event manually and trigger the object with that event like that?

```
var event = $.Event( "touchstart", { pageX:200, pageY:200 } );
```

I am using [this](http://interactjs.io/) for drag and drop, the author already mentioned there is no way to do this by interact js and recommended:

*- call your drag and drop listeners and give them event objects that you create or
- trigger simulated pointer events so that interact sees them as a drag by the user.*

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you declare the function outside the bind() and call it directly?

```
$(elem).bind('touchstart', handler);
function handler(event) {
    event.preventDefault();                  
    var target = $(event.target);

    //Do stuff with pageX and pageY
    target.css("margin-top", "50px"); 
}

handler({pageX:200, pageY:200, target:elem, preventDefault:function(){}});
```

Comment: Hi, this has the same effect, maybe I need a combination of touchstart, touchmove?! How can is set the position of target f.e x using touchmove? I need a simultaneously dragging..